# What is the best way to notify about new FOSCommentBundle:Comment?

Tags: symfony, foscommentbundle

I have AcmeBlogBundle:BlogPost entity and use FOSCommentBundle to comment it. All works fine, I just do:

```
{% 
    include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' 
        with {'id': 'blogpost' ~ blogpost.id} 
%}
```

And today I want to notify AcmeBlogBundle:BlogPost  owner about new comments to his post. **What is the best way to do this?**

1. I can save link to AcmeBlogBundle:BlogPost entity at AcmeBlogBundle:Thread (extends FOSCommentBundle:Thread) and then use it at thread persist events. But how can I save link, if Thread creates independently of BlogPost. And it's already not clean, because Thread will have dependency on BlogPost =(.
2. I can store Thread id like blog_post_{id} and then parse it thread persist events =(.
3. Store thread at BlogPost, but how I can to hook on creating Thread at concrete BlogPost.

And so on, and so on...

Sorry for my english, what is the best way to solve my problem?

**UPD1:** I have dupblicated question to https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/issues/367.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I have no time and today my dirty hack solution is https://gist.github.com/krasun/5599548. Tomorrow, I'll start bounty.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/issues/296) on how to use the event dispatcher with FOSCommentBundle.